# Scipy Interpolate only allows linear interpolation, otherwise throws error

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I am trying to interpolate values in a patchy lightcurve using `scipy.interpolate.interp1d`

It seems to work fine using linear interpolation, but raises the following error if I try and use quadratic or cubic interpolation:

`ValueError: Expect x to be a 1-D sorted array_like.`

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate

x = data2[:,0]
y = data2[:,1]
xnew = data3[:,0]
f = interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind='linear')  #This works for kind='linear', but not 'quadratic' or 'cubic'
ynew = f(xnew)
```

x and y look like this:

```
print x
>>> [55113. 55120. 55123. 55126. 55171. 55213. 55231. 55234. 55436. 55446.
 55474. 55475. 55480. 55497. 55505. 55508. 55514. 55556. 55568. 55570.
 55574. 55600. 55603. 55605. 55611. 55614. 55800. 55823. 55834. 55840.
...
58528. 58541. 58547. 58554. 58701. 58721. 58737. 58748. 58759. 58768.]

#=================

print y
>>> [0.01908541 0.01971167 0.0194646  0.01874254 0.01864027 0.01960122
 0.01862151 0.01850946 0.02040462 0.01998174 0.02093472 0.02075255
 0.02041515 0.02126069 0.02201405 0.02160587 0.02218664 0.0213718
...
0.01937561 0.01975203 0.01989411 0.01958265 0.0200566  0.01976214]
```

and then xnew is a linspace between min(x) and max(x) at integer intervals, i.e.

```
print xnew
>>> [55113. 55114. 55115. ... 58765. 58766. 58767.]
```

Finally some additional info about the input data:

```
print type(x)
print type(y)
print type(xnew)
print x.shape
print y.shape
print xnew.shape
>>> <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> (970,)
>>> (970,)
>>> (3655,)
```

Basically I don't understand the error - x is a sorted 1-D array, so I don't see the problem.

Here are the raw and linearly-interpolated lightcurves for visualisation purposes:

[Raw Lightcurve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLa0R.png)

[Linearly Interpolated Lightcurve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QL0Bu.png)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Would you mind trying to give `np.linspace(np.amin(x), np.amax(x), x.size)` instead of x in interp1d?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. It doesn't make sense to do that though because that completely changes the shape of the lightcurve - there are gaps which need to stay there, and doing `np.linspace` covers over all the natural gaps. It does allow me to do cubic interpolation with your method, but I need to be able to do it without having a perfectly sequential x-axis.
Here's a graph of what it looks like - blue is the original, orange is the new
[https://imgur.com/a/jKqxHdx]

Comment: What do you get if you execute `print(np.amin(x[1:] - x[:-1]))`? I think it has to be strictly greater than 0 for cubic interpolation to work.

Comment: Interesting, yeah that gives me exactly 0. What does that mean? And what can be done to overcome it?

Comment: It means that you have at least two consecutive points in x which are identical. This is why cubic interpolation fails.

Comment: Ohhh yes that makes a lot of sense actually, thanks for your help I think I should be able to fix it now! Cheers